# Остановка ввода в cin по Ctrl+Z

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте, у меня такой вопрос, мне нужно ввести через "cin>>" много символов, в которых и интер есть и пробелы, у них есть свои значения, мне нужно сделать так, чтобы ввод данных остановился, если я введу ctrl+Z, а до этого он закачивал все в массив, возможно ли это сделать на "cin"-е, я уже сделал на getch, но она проблематична, если возможно с помощью сина, подскажите пож как...

Answer (score 7):

Попробуйте так

```
int main( ){
     string data;
     while (cin.good()){
         cin >> data;
         ...
     }
}
```

Пока не встретилась ошибка чтения (в том числе конец файла), `cin.good()` будет возвращать `true`, и цикл будет читать данные.

Comment: Спасибо помогло очень!